# Export selected features to the same XLSX file as different tabs

Tags: qgis

I'm trying to extract selected features from multiple layers to the same excel spread sheet as different tabs. I can do this in FME but some people aren't familiar with FME.

I currently run Extract selected features in batch process but i can't make it go to the same spreadsheet.

The current work flow looks likes this:

- Select features
- Open extract selected features
- hit run as batch process
- Select the input layers
- Then select the output file
- Open the excel files
- Copy the contents of files to new file in different tabs

Ideally i would be able to do all this in QGIS.

Comment: QGIS makes a new TAB in Excel automatically, if you export your data to an existing Excel file

Comment: @eurojam When i run Extract selected features in batch process and select an existing .xlsx file it overwrites it and i only end up with 1 tab for 1 layer? How do i get it to create a new TAB?